# The standard way to get sizeof(promoted(x))

Tags: c++, sizeof, type-promotion

Is there a standard way to get the size of the type a variable would be promoted to when passed as a variadic argument?

```
auto x = ...;
auto y = sizeof(promoted(x));
```

The results should be:

```
char  -> sizeof(int)
int   -> sizeof(int)
float -> sizeof(double)
...
```

Comment: What exactly is your use case for this? It's an interesting problem, I just don't know what you'd the solution for.

Comment: @Borgleader I'm working on a embedded project (Cortex A5, and we would prefer not to exceed about 256k code size). The OS has two functions (in broad sense) implemented in different modules: (1) printf (2) enqueue_stuff/dequeue_stuff. The later takes a variable number of uint32_t. I want to enqueue_stuff -> dequeue_stuff -> printf.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can simply declare overloaded `promoted` functions with the proper types:

```
int promoted(char);
int promoted(short);
int promoted(int);
long promoted(long);
long long promoted(long long);
double promoted(float);
double promoted(double);
long double promoted(long double);
```

Note that the functions need no implementations, because we are never actually calling them.

Here is a simple test run which prints 1, 4 and 4, 8 on my machine:

```
std::cout << sizeof('a') << '\n';
std::cout << sizeof(promoted('a')) << '\n';

std::cout << sizeof(3.14f) << '\n';
std::cout << sizeof(promoted(3.14f)) << '\n';
```

Comment: Oh, and this does not work for unsigned types yet. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d85ccffcea22351) Tbh, I really dislike the idea of doing this by hand.

Comment: It's rather manual, but it's simple, easy to underatand, and works for both integral and floating even without C++11. Include unsigned stuff for practical usage.

Answer (score 19):

```
auto s = sizeof(+x);
```

should do the trick for integers.

`+x` makes use of the unary `+` operator, which performs integer promotion just like any other arithmetic operator.

I am not aware of any standard promotion rules for `float` that would apply here (in the integer promotion sense) since you can do arithmetic with them without promoting. If you always want to promote to at least `double` you can try

```
auto s = sizeof(x + 0.);
```

and then distinguish between floating point and integers before you get there.

Again, I do not think that you can handle integers and floating points at once because of the different meanings of "promotion" we are applying here.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on what exactly is going on with `+x` that allows this to work?

Comment: The trick is how do you get the floating point promotions (`4.6`)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour This is the best I can do. Should at least be usable like this. (I hope, I have no idea what OP is actually doing here.)

Comment: I like that this doesn't require writing any function prototypes/templates.

Answer (score 13):

To generalise Baum mit Augen's answer, you could write function templates like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto promoted(T) 
  -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, decltype(+T{})>;

template <typename T>
auto promoted(T) 
  -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, decltype(T{}+0.)>;

//usage
sizeof(promoted(a))
```

Or a version using type traits:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct promoted;

template <typename T>
struct promoted<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
{ using type = decltype(+T{}); };

template <typename T>
struct promoted<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>
{ using type = decltype(T{} + 0.); };

template <typename T>
using promoted_t = typename promoted<T>::type;

//usage
sizeof(promoted_t<decltype(a)>)
```

Comment: Might I suggest `template<class T> std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof(promoted_t<T>)> promote_size( T const& ) { return {}; }`.  Then we get `promote_size('a')` as a compile-time constant `4`.

Comment: A classic C++ answer. Beautiful code pretending to be horribly ugly.

Comment: I like this answer, and it seems like the way to go, but unfortunately no C++11 for me, so no `<type_traits>`. :-(